Intermittent Broken Image Links in Gmail for S3 Hosted Images
I programmatically send transactional emails with AWS SES that include HTML img tag image links pointing to the S3 URIs of objects in a public S3 bucket. Around ~20% of the time, the image link in the gmail client will be broken.
Each email always has the same 3 images: 2 PNGs at 100k and 1 PNG at 10k. The actual image link in the delivered email is a URL for gmail's image proxy, googleusercontent.com. The same image in different emails appears to always result in the same proxy URL. When I manually test these proxy URLs, they resolve to the correct images, although twice while testing I did get an initial 404 response before the URL returned the correct image on the next request.
I've thought about curl'ing one of these URLs in a watch to see how frequently it returns 404, but I'm not sure what I would do with the information if I had it.
Any ideas?
